# Autocomplete in Rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am attempting this in rails 3.2 with no success. In my application layout file I've got:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

In my new.html.erb I've got:

```
<%= form_for @aidmodel, :html => { :multipart => true }, remote: true do |f| %>
    <table class="signup_form">
            <tr>
            <td><%= f.label :brand %></td>
          <td class="inputfields"><%= f.text_field :brand %></td>
          </tr><tr>
```

In my new.js.erb I've got:

```
<%= raw @brands %>
```

In my application.js I've put at the bottom:

```
$(function() {

    $('#aidmodel_brand').autocomplete({
        source: '/aidmodels/new.js'
    });

});
```

And, lastly, here is my controller:

```
  def new
    @aidmodel = Aidmodel.new
    @brands = Aidmodel.all.map(&:brand).compact.reject(&:blank?)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    end
  end
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your "new.js.erb":

```
 <%= raw(@brands.map {|brand| escape_javascript brand}.to_json) %>
```

Comment: What is the error? Could you paste more info so I can help you?

Comment: Yeah, sorry... There is actually no error.. The page loads as normal but the autocomplete doesn't in the brand field. I couldn't see any errors on the server either. Is there somewhere I can look for an error?